# How to add a message to EditTextPreference?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I've extended [`EditTextPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/EditTextPreference.html) so I can customise it:

```
class DeleteAccountPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : EditTextPreference(context, attrs) {

    override fun setDialogMessage(dialogMessageResId: Int) {
        super.setDialogMessage(R.string.delete_account_message)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
        val box = holder?.itemView as AppCompatButton
        box.text = title
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
    }
}
```

However [`setDialogMessage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/DialogPreference.html#setDialogMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)) has no effect, the dialog only displays the title:

[image]

Here's my XML:

**preferences.xml**

```
<my.app.DeleteAccountPreference
    android:layout="@layout/preference_click"
    android:key="delete_account"
    android:title="Delete Account"
    android:summary="Type 'Delete' to delete your account."/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Simply add `android:dialogMessage="Message"` in xml:

```
<my.app.DeleteAccountPreference
    android:layout="@layout/preference_click"
    android:key="delete_account"
    android:title="Delete Account"
    android:dialogMessage="Type 'Delete' to delete your account."/>
```